# Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to spawn multiple daemons

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

When I just made my new project in android studio, I got an error even though I touched nothing!

```
Project ImagePro is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
                C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre
                Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
                spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
                while using Android Studio.
```

`ImagePro` is my project name which I just made it. I tried to figure out what is wrong but after reading many articles about this problem, I couldn't understand anything...

Please somebody help me... I'm going to be crazy if I read this error again...